# Period of trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

What is the period of $$\frac{7\sin x + 5\cos x}{7\sin{2x} + 11\cos x}$$

What should I do here? I don't even know where to start from. Please help me by giving me a hint!!

Thanks.

Comment: The period of the entire function is going to be the largest period of all of the trigonometric functions.

Comment: Well, it's really going to be the least common multiple of all the periods of the trigonometric functions, barring cancellation.

Comment: @mixedmath Two different answers? Help?

Comment: In this particular case, both answers coincide. But Brad's statement isn't true in general. It was an easy, honest mistake.

Comment: Sooo what do you mean by the least common multiple @mixedmath

Comment: If you have some numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$.  The least common multiple is the smallest number so that each $a_i$ divides it.  For instance, the least common multiple of $2$, $3$, and $8$ is $24$ because it is the smallest number that all of $2$, $3$, and $8$ divide.

Comment: Try replacing $x$ with $x + 2\pi$ and see if you can show that the expression simplifies to  original one. Show this isn't true if $x$ is replaced with $x  + \pi$ . ( When in doubt, graph the expression to see what is going on -- yes, I know you can't do this in a test situation.)

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Well that was pretty obvious. But don't understand it in terms of trigonometric functions.

Comment: @Alan How exactly will that help? I need to find the period of the function?

Comment: ^If you can show that $f(x+2\pi) = f(x)$, then you have shown that the function $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: Honestly , none of the tips offered seemed evident to me, so I graphed the function. I'm trying to make things as simple as possible.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I see. Let me try. But there has to be a more definite way? Rather than just trial and error?

Comment: @Alan Would $\pi$ be the correct answer?

Comment: @Gummybears Nope.

Comment: Hmmmmm....... I do get the same function over again though? @Hakim

Comment: If you find that the expression can be simplified to the original when $x$ is replaced by $x + \pi$ , yes.

Comment: Arghhh. This is just trial and error. Anyone with a more definite answer?

Comment: @Gummybears You made a mistake when calculating $f(x+2\pi)$, the correct answer is $2\pi$. I suspect that you're mistake was with the $7\sin2x$ term in the numerator, using the substitution $x\leadsto x+\pi$ yields $7\sin(2x+2\pi)$ and not $7\sin(2x+\pi)$.